# How to find memory leak in Python MXNet?

Tags: python, machine-learning, memory-leaks, amazon-sagemaker, mxnet

I am afraid that my Neural Network in MXNet, written in Python, has a memory leak. I have tried the MXNet profiler and the tracemalloc module to get an understanding of memory profiling, but I want to get information on any potential memory leaks, just like I'd do with valgrind in C.

I found [Detecting Memory Leaks and Buffer Overflows in MXNet](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MXNET/Detecting+Memory+Leaks+and+Buffer+Overflows+in+MXNet), and after managing to build like described in section "Using ASAN builds with MXNet", by replacing the "ubuntu_cpu" part in `docker/Dockerfile.build.ubuntu_cpu -t mxnetci/build.ubuntu_cpu` with "ubuntu_cpu_python", I tried executing in an AWS Sagemaker Notebook like this:

```
root@33e38e00f825:/work/mxnet# nosetests3 --verbose /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/run_predict.py
```

and I get this import error:

> Failure: ImportError (No module named 'run_predict') ... ERROR

My run_predict.py looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def run_predict(n):
  # calling MXNet inference method

run_predict(-1)  # tried it putting it under 'if __name__ == "__main__":'
```

What I am missing in my script, what should I change?

The example script they use in the link is [rnn_test.py](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/faccd91071cc34ed0b3a192d3c7932441fe7e35e/tests/python/unittest/test_rnn.py), but even when I run this example, I still get an analogous Import Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MXNet, we automatically test for this through examining the garbage collection records. You can find how it's implemented here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/c3aff732371d6177e5d522c052fb7258978d8ce4/tests/python/conftest.py#L26-L79